# how do i convert the given xml using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

IF I have a code like below.....

`<AAA>
    <XYZ>123</XYZ>
     <PQR>222</PQR>
<AAA>`

if the value of PQR is 222 then the output should be

`<AAA> XYZ-222 </AAA>`    (XYZ is the name of the preceding sibling)

if PQR is not 222 then print nothing..
`<AAA></AAA>`

IM new to XSLT, could you help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SO! No, if you are so new to XSLT that you can't give any try then we probably cant help out. We're not code writing service. However, if you have some code you tried and show it, we might to answer what's wrong with it.

Comment: The question suggests the `XYZ` does not have a fixed name. If this is the case, could the name of the `PQR` element also vary? (I.e. Are you actually after the value of the second child of `AAA` rather than one specifically named `PQR`?) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    <xsl:template match="AAA">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="PQR[text()='222' or preceding-sibling::XYZ]">
            <AAA>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(' XYZ-', PQR, ' ')"/>
            </AAA>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <AAA></AAA>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Use this code.